# When selecting sub-menu item it highlights all items under parent menu

Tags: css, html, menu, nav, submenu

I am working on a single page application and I have nested menu there, when I select any item on sub-menu it does highlight all sibling items under parent menu and parent menu itself, but what I need is just to highlight selected sub-menu and parent menu, please advise:

HTML

```
           <nav role="navigation">
                    <ul id="main_menu">
                        <li class="active"><a href="/travellist">Travel</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/advancedsearch">Advanced Search</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/creditcardmatcher">Credit Card Matcher</a></li>
                        <li id="maintenance_menu">
                            <a href="">Maintenance</a>
                            <ul id="sub_menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Admin Users</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Approval Categories</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Approval Groups</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Approval Sequence</a></li>
                                <li class="divider" style="background:white"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Category 4/5 Switch</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Employee Type</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Funding Type</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Help Maintenance</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Hire Status</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Job Title</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Offices</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Orientation</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="/help">Help</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </nav>
```

CSS

```
.main_header nav{
    background-color: #293955;
    height: 40px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    font-size:12px;
}

.main_header ul{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.main_header li{
    position:relative;
    float: left;
    display: inline;

}

.main_header  li:hover ul{
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    width:180px;
    background-color: #293955;
    padding:0px;
}

.main_header ul:after {
    content:".";
    display:block;
    height:0px;
    clear:both;
    visibility:hidden;
}

.main_header ul ul{
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    left:0px;
    width:0px;
}

.main_header nav a:link, .main_header nav a:visited{
    color: #FFF;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    height: 20px;

}

.main_header nav a:active,
.main_header nav .active a:link, 
.main_header nav .active a:visited{
    background-color: #4590d3;
    color: #FFF;
    text-shadow: none;
}

.main_header nav a:hover{
    background-color: #f3dd3e;
    color: #666;
    text-shadow: none;
}

.main_header nav li a{
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

.main_header nav li li a:hover{
    background-color: #f3dd3e;
    color: #666;
    text-shadow: none;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 1px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 1px;
    -moz-border-bottom-left-radius: 1px;
    -moz-border-bottom-right-radius: 1px;
    -moz-border-top-left-radius: 1px;
    -moz-border-top-right-radius: 1px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 1px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 1px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 1px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 1px;
    width:130px;
}
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#main_menu > li').click(function (e) {
        $('#main_menu > li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you want highlighted and when?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select only the main menu links to be highlighted when active. Change your CSS selectors for the active links to the following;

```
.main_header nav > ul > li > a:active,
.main_header nav > ul > li.active > a:link, 
.main_header nav > ul > li.active > a:visited
```

That way, the sub menu links will not appear active just because the parent is.

To additionally highlight the sub menu links when active add these selectors to the same CSS rule;

```
.main_header nav > ul > li > ul#sub_menu > li a:active,
.main_header nav > ul > li > ul#sub_menu > li.active > a:link, 
.main_header nav > ul > li > ul#sub_menu > li.active > a:visited
```

The `>` selector allows you to select only elements that have the correct direct parent.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot man the firs section did the trick of not highlighting everything under parent menu, but parent menu itself. However second section does highlight sub=menu only at the time of click. If I reopen sub-menu it does not stay highlighted. Is it expected behavior?

Comment: As far as the CSS is concerned, yes. You need the jQuery from matthias_h in the other answer to set the active class when you select a sub menu item. I also suggest you remove the `>`s from your original js so that selecting another sub menu item also removes the active class from the original sub menu item.

Comment: Got it. But also my sub-menu does not close after I click particular choice, until i move the mouse away.

Comment: It won't do. It's in focus. Is that a problem?

Answer (score 2):

I think I have a solution you can work with:

```
$('#sub_menu li').click(function () {
  $(this).closest('#sub_menu').parent('li').addClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Another problem is one css-rule you set, it's commented out in this fiddle:

```
.main_header nav a:active,
 /*.main_header nav .active a:link, */
.main_header nav .active a:visited { ...
```

This has to be rewritten - you have to set the active class for the active main menu
in a different way, but I think you can manage that :)
In the fiddle I removed all links from your html (at least I hope so), so it's more save to click.

Update - the $('#sub_menu li').click(function () has to be added to your existing #main_menu-click to set the class active to the clicked submenu entry. I can confirm that the css-suggestion from worldofjr in the other answer is working well and won't take any credit for it, so I don't update it in the fiddle.

Fiddle: [Menu highlight](http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/j7r185ac/)

Comment: some how the Fiddle doesn't work I mean it highlights on hover but doesn't stay highlighted after it has been clicked. I also had the code for the sub-menu but the menu code was overriding it. But thanks for the input anyway, I used your jquery example.

Comment: @superconsultant You're welcome. It's just a little misunderstanding going on - as provided in both answers you have to combine the css from worldofjr, your main menu and my submenu. I didn't  want to adjust my fiddle to the working solution because I didn't want to present my half-answer together with css taken from another answer, looks like a wrong thing to do somehow. Glad worldofjr and I were able to help you solve your problem.